# Calculate Sum of numbers with all possible combination

Tags: java, algorithm, variables, iteration, combinations

If there are certain numbers x<sub>0</sub> and x<sub>n+1</sub> , and if x<sub>i</sub> is an integer for 0 <= i <= n+1, how to calculate the sum of the numbers with JAVA?

The sum indicates that it takes the sum of f(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,...x<sub>n</sub>) for every possible combination of (x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,...x<sub>n</sub>) such that the inequality holds. The inequality is **x<sub>0</sub> < x<sub>1</sub> < x<sub>2</sub> < ... < x<sub>n+1</sub>**

I have an idea for the solution, but it is a terribly ineffective algorithm using binary, and it's O(2<sup>n</sup>). Of course, I cannot use "for" because it must be used for n (non-specific) times.

for example,

if given is x<sub>1</sub> = 1, and x<sub>n+1</sub> is x<sub>3</sub> = 5, then the possible combinations are

- x<sub>1</sub>=1, x<sub>2</sub>=2, x<sub>3</sub>=5
- x<sub>1</sub>=1, x<sub>2</sub>=3, x<sub>3</sub>=5
- x<sub>1</sub>=1, x<sub>2</sub>=4, x<sub>3</sub>=5

the sum should calculate sum for all these 3 possible value set.

Is there anyone who knows more effective algorithm for this?

Comment: Could you explain a little more what this algorithm is supposed to do. Perhaps in sudo code. Or paragraphs

Comment: And what does "sum(x_0<x_1<…x_n<x_n+1) f(x_1,x_2,…x_n)?" mean, its not any sum i've ever encountered

Comment: not fun here its stackoverflow

Comment: This algorithm is supposed to calculate the sum of the value of function f with n variables x_1,x_2,x_3,...x_n for all possible combination of these variables when they satisfy the condition that x_0<x_1<...x_n<x_(n+1).

Comment: ok, and what is function f

Comment: function f is just any mathematical function. The problem is how to calculate such sum.

Comment: Ok, perhaps give some example inputs and outputs that you would expect

Comment: If I use "for", I need to use "for" n times. So, I think there should be some recursive solution for this problem.

Comment: For example, (x_0,x_5)=(-1,5) 
Then, if f is just addition of its variables, the sum should be
(0+1+2+3)+(0+1+2+4)+(0+1+3+4)+(0+2+3+4)+(1+2+3+4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to solve this is to think of it as an attempt to find all combinations of `n` numbers between `min` and `max`. Adding them up as you go

You can imagine `n` stones on a number line between `min` and `max`, then moving the furthest right stone until it is at max, when it is you move the next furthest right stone up one place and move all stones to its right.

See this example where n=4, min=2 and max=11

[image]

This algorithm will ensure you get all combinations.

So with that algorithm in mind you could write functions

```
boolean[] getNextCombinations(boolean[] currentCombination) //which would advance to the next value (and probably return null when there are no more combinations)
```

and

```
int scoreCombinations(boolean[] currentCombination, int min, int max) //which would add up a particular combination
```

Comment: Thank you. Your graph helped me a lot to get how I should design the program. That's far faster than mine, so I don't have any problem now.